# Entity Framework error Cannot İmplicity convert type 'bool' to 'string'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I want to sync s.UrunNavigation.Uadi with Adi but It gives this error

> cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   'System.Func' because some of the return
>   types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate
>   return type

```
public ActionResult UrunMiktarIcin(string Adi, string OcakUrun) 
{

    string reply;
    if (OcakUrun == "urun")
    {
         reply = _context.UrunMiktari
            .Include(u => u.HangiOcakNavigation)
            .Include(u => u.UrunNavigation)
            .Where(s => s.UrunNavigation.Uadi = Adi)
            .Select(u => new 
            { 
                UrunAdi = u.UrunNavigation.Uadi, 
                OcakAdi = u.HangiOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak, 
                UrunSayisi = u.UMiktari
            });


    return Json();
}
```

My UrunMiktari Model:

```
public partial class UrunMiktari
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Urun { get; set; }
        public int UMiktari { get; set; }
        public int HangiOcak { get; set; }

        public virtual CayOcaklari HangiOcakNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Urunler UrunNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

My Urunler Model:

```
public partial class Urunler
    {
        public Urunler()
        {
            UrunCikis = new HashSet<UrunCikis>();
            UrunGiris = new HashSet<UrunGiris>();
            UrunMiktari = new HashSet<UrunMiktari>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Uadi { get; set; }
        public decimal SatisFiyati { get; set; }
        public decimal AlisFiyati { get; set; }
        public bool AktifPasif { get; set; }
        public string Barcodu { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UrunCikis> UrunCikis { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UrunGiris> UrunGiris { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UrunMiktari> UrunMiktari { get; set; }
    }
```

I try "s => s.UrunNavigation.Uadi == Adi"

`reply = _context.UrunMiktari.Include(u => u.HangiOcakNavigation).Include(u => u.UrunNavigation).Where(s => s.UrunNavigation.Uadi == Adi).Select(u => new { UrunAdi = u.UrunNavigation.Uadi ,OcakAdi = u.HangiOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak, UrunSayisi = u.UMiktari })`

It gives this error:

> cannot implicitly convert type 'system.linq.iqueryable <>to 'string'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   _context.UrunMiktari.Include(u => u.HangiOcakNavigation).Include(u => u.UrunNavigation).Where(s => s.UrunNavigation.Uadi == Adi).Select(u => new { UrunAdi = u.UrunNavigation.Uadi ,OcakAdi = u.HangiOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak, UrunSayisi = u.UMiktari })
```

returns a type of `IEnumerable<{ UrunAdi, OcakAdi, UrunSayisi }>`, not a type of `string`.

It looks like you want to return a json array?

try this

```
public ActionResult UrunMiktarIcin(string Adi, string OcakUrun) 
{

   if (OcakUrun == "urun")
   {
      var reply = _context.UrunMiktari
         .Include(u => u.HangiOcakNavigation) // this is not necessary because manually projecting
         .Include(u => u.UrunNavigation) // this is not necessary because manually projecting
         .Where(s => s.UrunNavigation.Uadi == Adi) // Had a single `=`, need `==`.
         .Select(u => new 
         { 
             UrunAdi = u.UrunNavigation.Uadi,
             OcakAdi = u.HangiOcakNavigation.NeredekiOcak, 
             UrunSayisi = u.UMiktari 
         });
      return Json(reply);
   }

   return Json();
}
```

You also have an assignment op (`=`), you need a comparison op (`==`).

Comment: Thank u so much It worked but `.Where(s => s.UrunNavigation.Uadi == Adi)` should be